# Platformio C++ multiple "multiple definition of"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio, multiple-definition-error

I can't resolve this problem on my arduino project. I am using Platformio on vscode.

I want to use the MFRC522_I2C library to read rfid badges so I created a class to use the libraries methods.

The library can be found here: https://github.com/arozcan/MFRC522-I2C-Library

Here is my code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "rfid/Rfid.hpp" // my rfid class

Rfid _rfid;
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    _rfid.setupRfid();
}

void loop()
{
    _rfid.rfidLoop();
}
```

Rfid.cpp:

```
#include "Rfid.hpp"

Rfid::Rfid(/* args */)
{
}

Rfid::~Rfid()
{
}

void Rfid::setupRfid()
{
  _rfidReader.PCD_Init();
}

void Rfid::rfidLoop()
{
    // here is my code to read the rfid
}
```

Rfid.hpp:

```
#ifndef _RFID_HPP_
#define _RFID_HPP_

#include "../lib/rfidReader/MFRC522_I2C.h" // the MFRC522 library

MFRC522 _rfidReader(0x28);

class Rfid
{
private:
  /* data */
public:
  Rfid(/* args */);
  ~Rfid();
  void setupRfid();
  void rfidLoop();
};

#endif
```

I got this error:

```
multiple definition of `_rfidReader'; .pio/build/m5stack-core2/src/main.cpp.o:[PATH]/src/rfid/Rfid.hpp:7: first defined here
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: offtopic: any symbols in global scope which start with an underscore are reserved for a compiler!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
MFRC522 _rfidReader(0x28);
```

is a *definition* of a variable. You can have only one single definition for each variable in your program.

Because you include the header file in two source files, it will be defined twice, once in each source file.

To solve your problem, *declare* the variable in the header file:

```
extern MFRC522 _rfidReader;
```

Then move the definition into a *single* source file.

---

Good things to learn related to this issue:

- [The one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)
- [Translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))

---

After checking the code some more it seems that the `_rfidReader` variable really should be a *member* variable of the `Rfid` class.

Then your header file would look like this instead:

```
#ifndef _RFID_HPP_
#define _RFID_HPP_

#include "../lib/rfidReader/MFRC522_I2C.h" // the MFRC522 library

class Rfid
{
private:
  /* data */
  MFRC522 _rfidReader;
public:
  Rfid(/* args */);
  ~Rfid();
  void setupRfid();
  void rfidLoop();
};

#endif
```

And in the source file the constructor should look like this:

```
Rfid::Rfid(/* args */)
  : _rfidReader(0x28)  // Initialize the member object
{
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well. ```extern MFRC522 _rfidReader;``` is already in the header file Rfid.hpp. Can I define ```Rfid _rfid``` in my main.cpp file?

Comment: @Antoine No it's not. You have `MFRC522 _rfidReader(0x28);` which is *very* different from `extern MFRC522 _rfidReader;`

Comment: @Antoine By the way, why is it a global variable? Why no make it a member variable of the `Rfid` class?

Comment: (I changed ```MFRC522 _rfidReader(0x28);``` to ```extern MFRC522 _rfidReader;```)

Comment: @Antoine Constructor initializer list. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks dude that is clear that way!